# Excel formula for filtering a list

Tags: excel, filter

```
Apple
Apricot
Avocado
Banana
Breadfruit
Apple
Blackberry
Blackcurrant
Blueberry
Boysenberry
Currant
Cherry
Cherimoya
Blueberry
Cloudberry
Coconut
```

I have the above list and I need to find an excel formula that detects all of the duplicates in the above list.

If the term has already appeared in the list, then the formula should display it on the same row, if the term has not already appeared on the list then the formula should display N/A.

I only managed to get the formula so that when the duplicate appears is displays Duplicate, something like this: `=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2, $B2)>1, "Duplicate", "N/A")`

Comment: Start in B2, as A1 can't be a duplicate of itself. `If(Match(A2,$A$1:$A1,0)>0,"Duplicate","N/A")`

Comment: Do you mean you want the value instead of the word Duplicate? Assuming your list is in column B, starting at row 2, you can just change your formula to `=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2, $B2)>1, $B2, "N/A")`

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, helped me very much ! Have a great day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean with

> then the formula should display it on the same row

Do you want to have some thing like:

```
Apple         N/A
Apricot       N/A
Avocado       N/A
Banana        N/A
Breadfruit    N/A
Apple         Apple
Blackberry    N/A
Blackcurrant  N/A
Blueberry     N/A
Boysenberry   N/A
Currant       N/A
Cherry        N/A
Cherimoya     N/A
Blueberry     Blueberry
Cloudberry    N/A
Coconut       N/A
```

?

If this is what you want your formula looks good, just a little change (considering I started at Cell "A1"):

From:

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A1)>1, "Duplicate", "N/A")

to

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A1)>1, $A1, "N/A")

And copy down

Comment: I had a task to do this and I got it sent back and thought I didn't do it well, but now after reading your answer I realize that this is what I needed to do. Thank you very much man, have a great day everybody !

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Have a great day :)